# How do I install PostGIS on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS

Tags: postgresql-12, ubuntu-20.04, dhis-2, postgis-installation

I have just set up a brand new Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I have successfully installed Postgresql 12

I want to install postgis, but I cannot find any instructions on the internet for my version of Ubuntu.

My aim is to set up a DHIS2 server to run a hospital management information system

Without crossing this hurdle, there is no way to proceed.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgis-on-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: Thanks so much, I did finally install it, I will update this post with the answer